# How to parse(append) value to existing xml file in oracle?

Tags: xml-parsing, plsqldeveloper

How to parse(append) value to existing xml file in oracle???
(I have standard fields in my xml file, i want to change that field value dynamically from oracle database).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT UpdateXML(XMLTYPE('**d**'), '/a/b/text()', 'c') FROM dual;

Comment: Help me gain some points if you find the solution correct..mark it